# Чтение файлов с удалённого компьютера с помощью Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

На удалённом компьютере в определенной папке лежат текстовые файлы, которые мне надо прочитать с помощью python на своём ПК. Как можно максимально просто это реализовать? Оба компьютера находятся в защищенной корпоративной сети

Comment: Уточните, какая ОС? Если Windows, то расшарить и подключить как удаленный сетевой диск, и тогда обращаться к нему локально, типа `\\Shared\file.txt`

Answer (score 2):

Вам нужно обратиться к администратору, он покажет правильный путь, по имени или по адресу или через тоннель, возможно будут нужны дополнительные права на файл и каталог.

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю, что Вы имеет в виду "защищенная сеть", но если сеть из windows машин, и на машине, к которой вы обращаетесь, на папке есть гостевые права, то прочитать можно так:

```
file_path = '//it/shara/text.txt'
with open(file_path, 'r') as txt_file:
    all_strings_from_file = txt_file.read().splitlines()
print(all_strings_from_file)
```